# How to sell or replace a frigate?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have a very weak frigate with only 1 star. I [learned](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Frigate) that

> ...the frigates themselves have 5-star ratings depending on their class
>   and traits. It is recommended that the total star rating of your
>   frigate team is at least 1 star higher than the difficulty of the
>   expedition. If the team rating is equal to the expedition rating there
>   is a chance that the frigates will be damaged, and if the team rating
>   is lower than the expedition, frigate damage is very likely. Also note
>   that lower class frigates are more likely to be damaged than higher
>   class ones. If a damaged frigate continues its mission and gets
>   damaged again, it will be destroyed and cannot be recovered.

Because my frigate always return damaged and only waste a lot of resources, I want to sell it or replace it with a better one.

How can I sell (or replace) a selected frigate?

Comment: You can also help prevent damage by adding Combat ships to the fleet and generally increasing its strength so it has the same or more stars than the mission, and adding booster items (that can be built once you get frigate upgrade items from Industrial missions and upgrade them via the upgrades terminal on the frigate bridge).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the hiring section of the page you have linked in your question:

> Dismiss unwanted frigates using the middle mouse button from the Manage Fleet panel.

In the control room for your freighter, there is a central command station that you can manage your fleet with.  From there, you should be able to do the above and dismiss your frigate (there should be a similar control on console versions of the game as well).  There is no warning indication for dismissing the frigate, and you do not getting anything back either.

To get another frigate, simply find another freighter fleet and approach it.  You will see a bunch of green icons appear on your screen indicating frigates available for purchase.  Once you get close enough, establish communications with the frigate in question and negotiate from there.  You can have a max of 30 at a time.

Comment: "Dismiss" seems pretty vague to me. Does it mean "destroy the frigate, kill the people and loose everything"? Or "Get your invested cash back"? Or "move the hired people to another frigate"? The middle mouse button destroys/break up almost always the selected thing. What exactly does it mean in this case?

Comment: @PeterCo I just tested myself in my game, and it simply just gets rid of it.  There is no warning indication either. I did not get any money back.  If you want to see for yourself, try it.  You can always go back to a previous autosave, like I did.

Comment: Thank you! Please add your results to your answer (instead of "I'm not sure if...."). I will accept it as answer.

Comment: @PeterCo Ok.  Also, you might as well keep the frigate for now since you can have 30 at a time.  Unless you are already at the max amount, it doesn't hurt to keep the lower level one around.

Comment: Good idea! I also try to send it together with higher level frigates, maybe this way I can level it up.